# Mono Develop and Visual Studio Compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, mono

Will code developed with Mono (Develop) be compatible with Visual Studio (2010 for now)? Meaning, is it ok to have some members of a team using mono develop (linux) and some using Visual Studio (windows)? Or should I expect problems?

For this project, it will be using C++ on Visual Studio 2010 (most members). If its compatible, can I expect the same from Visual Studio 2012? Except those specified on the Mono website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been a long time Visual C++ developer, you will know using Windows's stuffs (such as MFC) locks you up on Windows.

MonoDevelop's C++ support (for example GTK+) does not aim to clone Visual C++ or be compatible with it,

http://monodevelop.com/documentation/creating_c_and_cpp_projects

So I think the answer is No.

Comment: Actually this will be one of my first C++ projects ... so ... the purpose of mono will be to bring C#/F# *core language* functionality cross platform?

Comment: Primarily speaking, Mono means C#, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software). Its VB.NET support is limited, while F# support is from Microsoft's open sourced F#. So your understanding is not far away from the truth.